# Bound DataGridView with multiple sources

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

i have been strugeling with this for some time now and its driving me crazy. This is the situation:

I have a bounded `DataGridView` i designed this with the visual studio designer. All the information shows accordingly.

in my `DataGridView` i have 2 `ComboBoxes` in here the data is also correctly displayed. I want that if i click on the `ComboBoxe`a list of options shows.

Because the `DataGridView` is bounded to a source i can not use the `ComboBox.Items.Add()` method. So i created another  Datasource in the designer and in runtime i change the `datasource` for that specific combobox. **Now the list shows shows the options that i want, yeey !**

Now, i want to save this newly added or changed row to the database.. so i use the following method for this (i call the method on the `RowLeave` event from the `DataGridView`):

```
        if (tasksDataSet.HasChanges()
        {
            try
            {
                tasksBindingSource.EndEdit();
                tasksDataSet.GetChanges();
                tasksTableAdapter.Update(tasksDataSet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
         }
```

This won't work for the `ComboBoxes` since this is another datasource.

So basicly what i want is:

- Use a datasource for the `DataGridView`
- Change/Add items to the `DataGridViewComboBox`
- Save the changed made to the (complete) `DataGridView` to the database

How can i make this work ?

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is to save current data which is given to Grid view.
than i suggest try to use **session** . while binding data to DataSource assign it to 
session["SomeID"] . if your changing binding then again assign same session to it.

next step convert session to what ever you want to save.

ex:

```
        //Datasource.
        list<User> DataBoundSource = new list<User>();

        DataGrid.DataSource = DataBoundSource;
        DataGrid.DatBind();
        //Assign to Session where you are binding this
        //every time
        Session["SameID"] = lsDataBoundSOurce;

        //your code.
        ...
        ...
        ...

        //covert that session to Datasource you want to save.

        list<User> saveData = (list<User>) Session["SameID"];
```

this is the basic idea i got. i hop this will help you. 
please give it +1 if it help you

Comment: This will change the Datasource for the entire datagrid, the problem with saving is saving is that i have another Datasource for the combobox

Comment: i am not telling you to change the datasource. assign your datasource to session and then save that session by converting it. if possible please post some code so i can help you. Thanks for reply.